# Martian Brother

Tags: mars, life

According to some documentaries History and Discovery, fossils have been found in a meteorite that fell to earth. This meteorite came from Mars.

It is possible that the Martians always try to be bacteria or unicellular. It is possible that single-celled organisms that evolved into multicellular beings and then to beings we know.

So possibly we are Martians (acestral have a Martian, a bacterium).

My question is, does on Mars, before the earth existed humans?

If that were to be existed underground, or another planet were extinct?

If there were other humans on Mars, then we live in parallel ignorance of each other. So we may be extinct before meeting our Martian (or other planets now) brother?

Have we discovered but scare our discoverers by our violent attitudes and our boundless ambition?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about astronomy and realies heavily on speculation

Comment: Check the recent documentaries on the subject and you'll see that astronomy has studied the speculation of life on other planets. Curiosity as probes, Mars 2 and Mars had a mandate to identify life on other planets, I do not think it is off topic.

Comment: Check and reconsider your vote please.

Comment: Diego, your post is not exactly clear as to what you're asking. There seem to be a number of questions, and they are difficult to parse. If you could clarify and narrow your question (and it appears to be on topic at that point) I could reopen your question.

Comment: My question is: with the expansion of the solar system many materials were shared (as in response ticked), it is possible organism from Mars coming to Earth and evolved in parallel in the two planets, thus generating two races of humans?

Comment: @DiegoHillesheim There's really two huge separate questions here. 1) Could single-celled Martian organisms have come to Earth? 2) Could the same species of single-celled organism on two different planets evolve in parallel to produce humanoids on both? (And what is the likelihood this happened on Mars?) The first one is on topic here, but is still mostly speculative in the field of astronomy. The second would be more appropriate on Biology, but is still on topic here since it falls under astrobiology. It is so broad and speculative however that it could be debated endlessly (and is).

Comment: Thanks, but I consider this extremely important debate, why only hope theories fall into our laps? Why not try to understand through finds what may have happened?

Comment: @DiegoHillesheim It's not that forming theories based on our evidence is bad in general, but that it is not appropriate on this site. This site is for definitive answers. None can currently be given to this question.

Comment: Then, I'm sorry.

Comment: That's actually an intriguing question that Diego raises.  In case the point has been obscured by the language of the question, Diego is suggesting that microbial life in this solar system may have first arisen on Mars, and then been transplanted to Earth via impact splatters.  In that case it might be accurate to say that we are actually Martians!  But I agree: the question is too highly speculative for the site.

Comment: Yes, I consider this very interesting.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist there is not yet any concrete evidence to support these suggestions, so as called2voyage says, it is not an appropriate topic for this site.

Comment: @Moriarty, I wasn't disputing that, just commenting that it was an interesting question in its own right.

Comment: Are you talking about panspermia?

Comment: I'm talking about meteors with microorganisms coming from Mars that may have populated the earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's exceedingly unlikely, that human-like species ever existed on Mars, from all we know thus far.

It's very likely, that matter has been exchanged between Earth and Mars by asteroids, especially from Mars to Earth, and especially in the early solar system.

It's very likely, that Mars was habitable for microorganisms in its early history, although there is no definitve evidence yet, that there ever existed life on Mars. We only know, that it could have survived for some time (millions of years), if it ever existed. But there are reasonable arguments, that there could have existed microbial life on Mars. A lot of effort is on the way to find evidence for this hypotheses.

Hence it cannot be ruled out, that we have Martian ancestors. No observational evidence at all exits yet to verify this hyptheses.

There are reasonable arguments, that there could be underground extant life on Mars, although no experimental evidence at all has been found until now. But probes to investigate this are planned.

We didn't discover life on other planets, we are searching, and don't scare.